# SASS bundling and minification works locally but not on Azure Websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sass, azure-web-app-service, bundling-and-minification, azure-devops

I have setup SASS bundling with Bundle Transformer: Sass and SCSS and it works great locally in debug and release mode, it builds through Azure Build Server, and delivers without any build issues to my Azure Web Site.  Problem is that it doesn't appear that the SASS is compiling into CSS.  Looking at the source on live site this shows for the CSS:

```
<link href="/Content/test?v=" rel="stylesheet">
```

without the hash that you'd expect, and see locally. Looking at the stylesheet there is nothing in it.

Code that I have to make the bundle:

```
var commonStylesBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Content/css");
commonStylesBundle.Include("~/Content/site.scss");
commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
commonStylesBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(commonStylesBundle);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have registered a bundle with the address "~/Content/**css**", but try to get the bundle with the address "/Content/**test**".

In addition, is not recommended to use the `CssMinify` and `JsMinify` classes together with a Bundle Transformer. I will not explain why it should not do, because I have written about this in the documentation (http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/documentation). As most simple solution to this problem I recommend to install the BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax (http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax) package.

Comment: In addition, I recommend to read a [«Less failure on Production Server»](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/discussions/429707) discussion.

Comment: The final fix is included in the Less discussion commented by Andrey.  Although I did have the wrong bundle address above it wasn't the final problem.  The final problem was that we needed to set in the .SCSS file's properties to "Build Action: Content" and that fixed the problem.